# Building Kotlin projects with Gradle sometimes fails with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I can't reliably reproduce this problem because it is sporadic. This is what I get when I build a **Kotlin** project with **Gradle**:

```
Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
:myproj:compileKotlin FAILED
1 actionable task: 1 executed
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kotlin.Unit
warning: the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-Xbuild-file' is specified
Exception in thread "Thread-25" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kotlin.Unit
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.UtilsKt$runToolInSeparateProcess$readErrThread$1$1.invoke(utils.kt)
    at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.forEachLine(ReadWrite.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.UtilsKt$runToolInSeparateProcess$readErrThread$1.invoke(utils.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.UtilsKt$runToolInSeparateProcess$readErrThread$1.invoke(utils.kt)
    at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:18)
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kotlin.Unit
...
```

I run Gradle with the following options

- `gradle assemble --no-daemon --parallel`
- I tried this within Docker and on my local machine as well (this even happens on the CI server as well)
- this error is completely sporadic I was not able to pinpoint a cause
- it happens with single and multi-module projects as well
- removing the `--parallel` or adding `--daemon` option does not help
- I'm using Gradle `4.2`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Gradle version?

Comment: Can you post here the list of your dependencies with their versions?

Comment: I updated my question. My dependencies do not matter becase this happens with all kinds of Kotlin projects.

Comment: @AdamArold It matters if you are using different versions of `Kotlin` for two `Kotlin` dependencies

Comment: Please provide at least the version of Kotlin gradle plugin.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue with Kotlin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18300). Unfortunately at this time we don't know what exactly causes it.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of this problem is related to use of two or more different Kotlin version. In my case, I use Android Studio 3 and IntelliJ IdeaU 2017. The solution that I used and it worked is:

- check your Kotlin version in either IDE. In this case, you should update the Kotlin's compiler to the same version.
- If you use just one IDE, the best possible solution is to remove your IDE and all caches.

For more information, please refer to [Kotlin community](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/errors-following-getting-started-with-intellij-idea-page/1588).