# Kotlin gradle Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinSourceSetProviderImplKt

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin

I tried to use gradle for transpiling Kotlin to Js. When I run the example from https://www.codeflow.site/fr/article/kotlin-javascript I got the error :
*Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinSourceSetProviderImplKt* which comes from line *apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'* of *build.gradle*.

I have no idea of what the missing class is and why kotlin2js is asking for it. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 148):

Solved this issue by setting the latest Kotlin version (1.3.72) in build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
ext {
    kotlinVersion = '1.4.20'
    springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
... 
}
```

Comment: This is confusing: You may not use kotlinVersion variable at all and instead hardcode version numbers in their classpath lines. I think the right answer should include the classpath line at least.

Comment: There's a number of ways to declare which Kotlin version to use, it could be plugin version in classpath like "classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" or hardcoded "classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72" or it can be "kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72" in plugins session. Most important is that the older Kotlin version (below 1.3.72 in my case) number was causing the issue.

Answer (score 36):

I just had the same issue. On windows, I checked the kotlin version from the command line with `gradle -v` and then **adjusted the kotlin version in  build.gradle** of my project to match my version of `gradle`.

I hope this works for you too.

Comment: The answer means you should update `kotlin_version` in grade-project, not grade-app.

Answer (score 33):

In my case this solves the problem:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
    }
}
```

Set `ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"` and
`$kotlin_version`

Answer (score 30):

Yes, as many before have said, the problem is probably that you have a kotlin version mis-match. But how do you know what version of kotlin is installed?

**To find out your version of kotlin:**
Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Kotlin

[image: picture of settings]

Make sure that you change your kotlin version (in both build.gradle files!) to this exact number.  In my case (above) it's 1.4.10

Good luck!

Answer (score 16):

In Android Studio:
File -> Project Structure -> Variables

There edit the `kotlin_version` to e.g. `1.3.72`

Gradle should resync automatically, otherwise resync manually

Answer (score 8):

update your Version in your gradle.properties file. eg) kotlinVersion=1.3.72

Answer (score 6):

Simplest solution:

Go to `file -> project structure (ctrl+shift+alt+s) -> suggestions -> accept all the suggestions.`

To answer the OP's quetion, you just need to accept the one with the `kotlin version`

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is a problem with different Ktlin verion as explained in [Building Kotlin projects with Gradle sometimes fails with NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648318/building-kotlin-projects-with-gradle-sometimes-fails-with-noclassdeffounderror)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I can do the same as KP7984 said - to check the versions of the plugins of my Android Studio, not the ones of my OS. I use `gradlew -v` of my project instead of `gradle -v` and it works for me.

Comment: If have trouble reading this as an attempt to answer the question at the top of this page. There is some insight hidden here, but a lot reads like "I need....", "my problem ...", "cannot use other answer ...". All of that are not considered an answer here. So please, could you [edit] and focus on the helpfully answering part of this? Anything which is not part of the answer you can move into a comment on your own post.

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle` file if you hover over the `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` it will tell you what version of Kotlin you will have to use in the `kotlinVersion` variable at the top of the file, according to your SDK/plugins versions.