# Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinSourceSetProviderImplKt by running gradle run via cmd

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a question about gradle:

I Have the following code in Kotlin (just started to learn it):

```
@file:JvmName("KtlTest")


fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    println("Hello Kotlin !")
}
```

and the following build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.51'
}

group 'KGroupId'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
ext.kotlin_version = '{{ site.data.releases.latest.version }}'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.3.1'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

task runExample(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'KtlTest'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

If I run this via IntelliJIDEA by clicking green triangle near task - it runs ok.
But, if I run it via other -> runExample in Gradle tab in IntelliJIDEA I got this error:
[image]

Also, I got this error if I try to run it via CMD:
[image]

Could someone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833542/kotlin-gradle-could-not-initialize-class-class-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-inter
didn't help me

Comment: Do you need this specific `runExample` task? In general, the best way to run Kotlin in Gradle is to create a sample project with New project wizard in IDEA, it will create the necessary build script automatically.

Also, it's highly recommended to use the latest version of Kotlin IDE plugin and Gradle plugin 1.3.72.