# Android Studio : Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

After git cloning from [here](https://github.com/VoiceGym/voicegym),

I first faced with this error:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\...\voicegym\app\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinSourceSetProviderImplKt
```

following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833542/kotlin-gradle-could-not-initialize-class-class-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-inter), i added these to `build.gradle (Project: voicegym)`

```java
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.72' // previously  '1.2.60'
    ext.springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    ext.anko_version='0.10.4'
    repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Now, i have this error

```
Build file 'C:\...\voicegym\build.gradle' line: 5

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'voicegym'.
> Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Comment: seems like something wants `kotlin_version` but you have defined `kotlinVersion`

Comment: @a_local_nobody so should i set `ext.kotlin_version= '1.3.72'` or should i set `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion "`

Comment: not really sure honestly, just make sure you use the same reference everywhere

Answer (score 11):

after experimenting, it should be `ext.kotlin_version=...` instead of `ext.kotlinVersion =...`

```java
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version= '1.3.72' // previously  '1.2.60'
    ext.springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    ext.anko_version='0.10.4'
    repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do to fix this error is to add the following line in *ext* component inside "Android/build.gradle(Project:projectName) file:

```
kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
```

The *ext* component will look like:

```
ext {
    activityVersion = '1.4.0'
    appCompatVersion = '1.4.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.1.2'
    coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
    coroutines = '1.5.2'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.4.0'
    materialVersion = '1.4.0'
    roomVersion = '2.3.0'
    // testing
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.4.0'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.3'
     //Add the kotlin version here:
    kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside android/build.gradle file place below code:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
 }
}
```

Inside app/build.gradle file place below code:

```
dependencies {
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On sdk 46 or higher, your 'gradle.build' should look like this:

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '33.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        if (findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')) {
            kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')
        }
        frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
```

Just replade it with this:

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '33.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        kotlinVersion = 'X,Y,Z' // <-- Pass your android version here
        frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
```

As seen above you'll need to find your android version
`Mac: Click Android Studio -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin`

You should see something like this: 213-`1.7.20`-release-for...

The second set of digits are your android version.

Your dependencies should also look like this:

```
dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion") // <-- Add this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add ext.kotlin_version= "1.3.72"
like this

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
```

the error will definetly resolved