# React native Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.DefaultKotlinSourceSetKt

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

[image]

[image]

Already tried multiple solutions suggested in [Kotlin gradle Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KotlinSourceSetProviderImplKt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60833542/kotlin-gradle-could-not-initialize-class-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-ko)

But nothing works so far. Any idea what is the root cause?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.